# Required attribute is not working in registration form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, required

I have a register form which works with Vue and local storage, when I submit the form blank or leave out an input the data is going to the local storage the same and not showing the HTML validation which is used by adding `required` attribute. Is there any way I can fix this problem by showing the HTML validation if the form has inputs which are empty or if the email do not have an at-sign inserted.

Form:

```
<form id="signup" method="post" v-on:submit.prevent>
    <br>
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <label for ="studentsorparents">Student or parents:</label>
    <input type="text" id="studentsorparents" v-model="studentsorparents" required ="required">
    <br><br>
    <label for ="username">username:</label>
    <input  type="text" id="username" v-model="username" required ="required" v-text="null">
    <br><br>
    <label for="email">email: </label>
    <input  type="email" id="email" v-model='email' required ="required">
    <br><br>
    <label for="password">password: </label>
    <input  type="password" id="password" v-model='password' required ="required">
    <br><br>
    <button v-on:click='onSubmit' onclick="passuseremail()" >Register</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var signupApp = new Vue({
    el: '#signup',
    data: {
        studentsorparents: '',
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    },


    methods: {
        onSubmit: function () {
            // check if the email already exists
            var users = '';
            var studentParent = this.studentsorparents;
            var newUser = this.username;
            var newEmail = this.email;
            if (localStorage.getItem('users')) { // 'users' is an array of objects
                users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
            }

            if (users) {


                if (users.some(function (user) {
                    return user.username === newUser

                })) {
                    alert('Account already exits');
                    return;
                }

                if (users) {
                    if (users.some(function (user) {
                        return user.email === newEmail

                    })) {
                        alert('Account already exits');
                        return;


                    } else {

                        alert('Account created');
                        window.location.href = 'user-profile.html' + '#' + newUser;
                    }
                }
                users.push({
                    'studentsorparents': studentParent,
                    'username': newUser,
                    'email': newEmail,
                    'password': this.password
                });
                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
            } else {
                users = [{
                    'studentparents': studentParent,
                    'username': newUser,
                    'email': newEmail,
                    'password': this.password
                }];
                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
            }
        }
    }

    });

function passuseremail()

{
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        localStorage.setItem("user-check", username);
        var studentsorparents=document.getElementById('studentsorparents').value;
        localStorage.setItem("students-parents-check", studentsorparents)
        var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
        localStorage.setItem("email-check", email)
         return false
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what's going on, but this definitely needs clearing out:  v-on:click='onSubmit' onclick="passuseremail()"  A button click triggers the form submit, the events on the button mess this up. If you want you can fully remove the form and focus on the function that handles your form.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add button `type='submit'` to the submit button else it will behave like just any other button.

```
<button v-on:click='onSubmit' onclick="passuseremail()" type="submit">Register</button>
```

It then only act as submit button else it will just trigger the button eventlisteners attached.

Comment: As far as I know there is no button that wont submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces after `required` attributes in your inputs:

> required ="required"

It's incorrect and it will not work; just write it like this:

```
<input type=email id=email v-model=email required>
```

---

You can validate email like this:

```
const email_re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+$/;

if (email_re.test( email.value )) {
    /* email is valid */
} else {
    /* email is not valid */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the button like jsValidateRegister.
And the add the code
First declare a variable

```
isPageValid = true
```

Then in add the following code for validation so the isPageValid is set to false inside the passuseremail();

```
$(".jsValidateRegister").click(function ()
{
    passuseremail();    
});
```

In the  onSubmit: function () check

```
isPageValid === true
```